# Detect Other User Location

Tags: android, google-maps, android-location

I want to build an android app that detect other user position in real time (like Uber app when the driver went to pickup customer).

[Capture of Uber App - Pick Customer]

[image]

I don't know the right way to build it, but i tried to build it with this trick.

[Store And Select User Location]

[image]

This trick was success. 
But...the problem are..

1. With that trick, there is no information for estimated time arrival.
2. if I wanna force estimate time arrival info, i have to send Direction Request API to google Maps, and it will make my limit request API Running Out Faster.

Big Appreciates for Any Help, links or examples.

Thank you.

Maulana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that my suggestion is to introduce server. If admin need location of any particular user(use id to identify), then admin app will inform server (by api call). Then the server will push the particular device (hosting id ) to update periodically about the device location. Now the user app will get the notification(push is the best way here) and start updating server about current co-ordinates(again by api call) and whenever the server will receive the updated location it will inform to the admin(via push/long pulling/tcp socket).

**Or**

You can use device to device communication, for that admin must have all the map of userId vs. gcm push id. Now if admin want to track any of user then it will push notification to the particular device (Via push). Whenever any of user device get such notification then it will start pushing back the current co-ordinates periodically.

If you need distance and time mapping, then better to find it via Google Api first. Let suppose google apis response says that distance is 2km(apiDistance) and it will take 8 min(apiTime) to move from carLat, carLang to your current position(let say userLat, userLang). Now for every location update use the simple distance mapping algo to find the distance remains :

```
    private double distance(double carLat, double carLang, double userLat, double userLang) {
      double theta = carLang - userLang;
      double dist = Math.sin(deg2rad(carLat)) * Math.sin(deg2rad(userLat)) + Math.cos(deg2rad(carLat)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(userLat)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(theta));
      dist = Math.acos(dist);
      dist = rad2deg(dist);
      dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
       return (dist);
    }

   private double deg2rad(double deg) {
      return (deg * Math.PI / 180.0);
    }
   private double rad2deg(double rad) {
      return (rad * 180.0 / Math.PI);
    }
```

Now you have apiDistance and apiTime(by last google Api call) and updatedDistance, so you can easily find out updatedTime (that will be approximate). For correction you can make google api call after a standard time(might be 1 min.) that will improve the accuracy.

Hope it will help you, Let me know if you need further assistance :)

Comment: Hi Neo,
as you can see in my diagram, for periodic updated coordinates (Latest other User Location) is no problem anymore.
the problem is how to get estimated time arrival without request API to googlemapAPI, because it will make my request API limit running out faster. Tq

Comment: Updated my answer, kindly check :)

Answer (score 0):

> Using gcm(Push notification)

**Steps:**

1. Make a webservice where you can get latlng and userid and save into database.And push this data using Gcm script to target device.
2. Integrate target device to accept push notification.
3. Call this web-service from android device of user periodically in background using android background service.

**How it works:**

Take an example master slave, slave periodically calls the web service with request parameter as lat,lng,userid,mastergcmid.When this webservice called, server push this lat lng to the mastergcmid.simple isn't it?

Optionally you can save the received lat, lng and userid into database for tracking record.

**Imp note:**

Be aware while using background service, put the appropriate stop condition like in notification bar. Continuously calling web services costs the internet data and cpu uses. But we have no other batter option as far as i know
Tell me if you find difficulties to implement this.

> Using socket

This is very good method for direct communicating between devices,here no need to use any kind of web service.

**How it works:**

Here one device works as a server and other as client,In your case client should be user who sends the loation, and server should be user who receives the location. So client connects to the server via ip address and port number if connection successfull then client can sent the message in your case lat,lng,userid.

**Imp note:**

I've build demo on socket messaging, but it works on same networks.I have not checked this on different network.

Comment: I'll try it.
Thanks Smit for the Clues. :)

Comment: @Maulana Okay sure,If you find it usefull please upvote it and when it work then kindly accept it.This is only motivation for us

Comment: not quite answered my problem but many thanks for giving me clues about gcm and lmp.
new homeworks for me. :)
thanks a lot Smit.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of apps you must have to implement a web-server which manages all the tasks.

Now for your problem. you should know that the uber app you are talking about has a estimated arrival time but this never works in many cases. you should take a look at this [article](https://www.quora.com/Is-Uber-getting-less-accurate-at-estimating-how-far-away-the-car-is-either-on-purpose-or-because-the-system-is-worse-at-calculating/answer/Tom-Goodwin-9?srid=u5q2L). they all estimate the duration on their own algorithms and the data collected from day to day basis. so now you have two ways to get this going-

1. You go for google direction api and get the most accurate arrival time to the client , which also take in account the current traffic condition and the weather condition.

   This is a limited quota request so it will not support you of you have a large client base and you dont buy extra quota from google.
2. The second way is to go for your own algorithm. you collect the data from the city or locality you are working on. ***the traffic condition at different parts of the city at different time of the day***. and then apply them with the ***normal allowed speed*** to vehicles at the road. this will give you the estimated arrival time.

   This calculation will be done at the server side and this will not have a limit for request. the more you collect the data, the more your estimated arrival time will be.

Comment: Very enlightening Explanation.
Thanks Sagar. :)

Comment: consider up-voting if you like this .

Comment: Not have voting rights yet. 
Reputation below 15. :(